# Karma how to test this angular code?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

```
$scope.login = function(){

  api.getToken($scope.username, $scope.password, function(){

    $scope.loggedIn = true;

  });
};

it('should work', function(){
  scope.login();
  expect(scope.loggedIn).toBe(true); // fails
});
```

How would I test this function? Testing against `scope.loggedIn` fails as it remains `false`.

Comment: Is that all of your test code? You would need to mock `api.getToken` and resolve it to set logged in to true.

Comment: If you look for documentation on angular testing, you will find references to `spyOn`. That's what you need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your api makes http requests, You can use $httpBackend to mock http calls 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

something like this:

```
var $httpBackend;

beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
}

it('should work', function(){

  $httpBackend.expect('POST', 'http://my-api/login').respond(200, { status: "ok" });
  scope.login();
  $httpBackend.flush();
  expect(scope.loggedIn).toBe(true); // fails
});
```

Comment: Yes it does, api.getToken returns an object. Could you possibly write me an example? I'm struggling with the syntax on this as api is a separate entity to the function I'm testing.